# What can i do to get my divs to float right?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one is 'Social Media', and the other is 'English'. I want to float them right so English can be first and then Social Media last, but when I float both to the right English passes social media and takes its place and social media takes English's place. What is my issue?

Please check out the link with the code to see the preview. Scroll to the far right to see the problem.

https://jsbin.com/dajaramame/edit?html,css,output

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are working well. When you use `float: right` the first item in the HTML will appear on the right and the second to its left. So you have to change social div with language.

### [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/memezihaja/1/edit?html,css,output)